# Creating a simple IVR Menu

Tags: asterisk, ivr

I'm an asterisk newbie to asterisk and i'm yet to fully understand the demo menu below. I have an overview but i'm not quite clear on the s's and the n's, the 1's, 2's. The basic functions like playback, goto etc, are quite clear. But not how n(loop) affects the menu.
Any help to clarify this would be appreciated.

```
[demo-menu]
exten => s,1,Answer(500)
   same => n(loop),Background(press-1&or&press-2)
   same => n,WaitExten()

exten => 1,1,Playback(you-entered)
   same => n,SayNumber(1)
   same => n,Goto(s,loop)

exten => 2,1,Playback(you-entered)
   same => n,SayNumber(2)
   same => n,Goto(s,loop)
```

Comment: doesn't asterisk support vxml?

Comment: Sure asterisk not support vxml.But can be controled by external vxml ap.

Answer (score 1):

Description

```
same => n(loop),Background(press-1&or&press-2)
```

"Same" here is "exten => s", "n" is next-pririty, "(loop)" is label for goto.

I recommend you read "Asterisk the future of telephony" O'Relly's book.

Comment: Thanks, the book is really a life saver.